# How does twisted read /etc/hosts?

Tags: python, proxy, dns, twisted

By default, Twisted reads `/etc/hosts` when connecting to websites on Linux systems. I'm just wondering which twisted file chooses  `/etc/hosts`, So I can go in and change it to a file of my choosing?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Twisted change hosts file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36960315/twisted-change-hosts-file)

Comment: i guess its just a question not much ppl know the answer to :(

Comment: Are you sure _Twisted_ reads that file? Perhaps the network stack on your OS simply respects that file when looking up IP addresses?

Comment: I'd spent a few minutes reading up on twisted tonight. There's an internal DNS resolver that it uses. If I get the time, I'll dive in a little deeper but for now [this link](http://nullege.com/codes/show/src%40t%40w%40Twisted-13.2.0%40twisted%40names%40tap.py/132/twisted.names.hosts.Resolver/python) might be able to help you.

Comment: thanks, I'll dive into this, seems promising

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code you're looking for is in the [Resolver Object line 621](http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/browser/tags/releases/twisted-9.0.0/twisted/names/client.py#L521). If you want to change the behavior of the resolver you pass in the required hosts file as follows.

```
from twisted.names import client
from twisted.internet import reactor

def do_lookup(domain):
    hosts = "/tmp/example"
    resolver = client.createResolver(servers=None, resolvconf=None, hosts="/tmp/example")
    d = resolver.getHostByName(domain)
    d.addBoth(lookup_done)

def lookup_done(result):
    print(result)
    reactor.stop()

domain = b'twistfoo.com'
reactor.callLater(0, do_lookup, domain)
reactor.run()
```

Comment: I actually have tried using this, but It just makes my script timeout, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36971934/createresolver-in-twisted-not-working If you know why it does that that would be awesome!